# What flash triggers can remotely set the mode and power on multiple flashes?

Tags: off-camera-flash, wireless-triggers, wireless-flash

Currently I own a Canon 60D, some lenses, a Metz Mecablitz 58 AF-2 flash and two Yongnuo YN-622C flash triggers to fire the flash off camera. One sits on top of the camera, and the other one goes on the flash.

What I am finding though is that with my single flash I cannot blow out the background to white because the flash is not powerful enough. Therefore, I have concluded that I need at least one, probably two, more flashes (both of these new flashes would face the wall to blow it out).

With these two new flashes, though, I will also need (1) light stands (2) umbrellas or softboxes (probably softboxes as there would be less light spilled); but most importantly I will need 3) some new triggers to control my two new flashes.

My current Yongnuo YN-622C flash triggers cannot change the flash mode and power from the camera (either via the camera menu or the trigger on top of camera, which would save me from having to go over to the flash, fiddling with it and getting back into position to take my photo. With more than one flash, I would really like to have this ability.

**Question - What triggers are available that allow you to change the mode and power of multiple flashes from where you stand?**

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly use Canon's built-in optical wireless eTTL system with the Metz 58 and the pop-up flash of your 60D.  But all you need are radio triggers that can communicate TTL and the flash menu control commands, and a flash that understands those signals. TTL-capable radio triggers include RadioPopper's PX units, PocketWizard's TTL triggers, Pixel Kings, Phottix Odins, and **those Yongnuo 622 triggers you already own.**

The YN-622c triggers you have actually *do* support this capability—so long as the flash speaks eTTL-II and can be commanded via the camera menu. It should work just fine with a for-Canon Metz 58.  I use YN-622C triggers with a 580EXII and YN-568EX, and get exactly the function you describe: I can set the manual power level (or ratio) on each flash remotely from the camera menu, and use high-speed sync, eTTL-II, etc.

To control more than one flash, simply get additional YN-622c triggers to act as receivers for each flash.  If the interface of the YN-622 is too cryptic, you may want to consider getting a YN-622C-TX transmitter; its LCD screen is easier to understand than the indicator lights on a 622C.

Suggest you read up on [CliveyBoy's Other YN-622C User Guide](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B77OmmGIg0gMVFpqNkpBYXBHajA/edit?pli=1), to see where you might be going wrong in setting up your gear.  If you're still stumped, try posting in the [POTN YN-622c monster thread](http://photography-on-the.net/forum/showthread.php?t=1212530) for help.

Common problems to check:

- On-camera YN-622c is properly seated
- Batteries are freshly recharged and in good health (some folks swear by alkaline over NiMH)
- Triggers are set to the same channel
- Flash is *out* of slave mode (i.e., flash ignores the hotshoe in slave mode and only listens to the optical sensor panel.)
- Try resetting the triggers, as per the [TOYUG](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B77OmmGIg0gMVFpqNkpBYXBHajA/edit?pli=1).

Comment: If I recall correcctly (I am sure someone will point it out if I am not), only groups A and B can have controlled ratios.  Group C is actually designed for blowing out the background, and always fires at full strength.

Comment: Yes, Group C is independent, but can be varied ±3EV with FEC , so doesn't *have* to be at full power all the time.

Answer (score 0):

While not strictly triggers, official Canon Speedlites support this functionality across the range with either a speedlite transmitter or a 580 or 600EX flash on the camera.  You can either control them from the transmitter itself or from the camera itself on some models.

I'm not sure if this is relevant to your situation since you already have some flashes, but it is how I handle controlling flash power remotely.

Comment: thanks, I have invested considerable money in flash and triggers already but I guess it would still be better to know that I can't control power and mode of any 3rd party triggers now than further down the track when I am even more invested.

Comment: @yoshiserry - and note, I'm not saying you can't remotely control it on other triggers, there is probably something out there, but I do it with first party stuff.  I more made this answer for anyone considering similar needs that hasn't bought flashes yet.  Hopefully someone else knows a trigger only solution.

Answer (score 0):

As near as I can tell, the combination you own already should allow you to control flash intensity remotely.  The YN-622C supports ETTL-II, and [this review](http://flashhavoc.com/yn622c_review/) indicates that it should be able to control multiple flashes when used with your 60D.  It also lists the Metz 58 AF-2 as a "full remote control" flash, so I'm puzzled that you'd be experiencing trouble with the combination you already own.

In my experience with a YN-622C and a Yongnuo YN568EX II flash, it's easy to set the flash in "manual" mode, rendering trigger control moot.  The simplest indicator (that I've found) that the camera is "talking" to the flash is to mount a zoom lens on the camera and half-press the shutter, then zoom and repeat.  If the flash is in ETTL communication with the camera, the flash zoom will attempt to follow the lens.  You can also fire a couple of test shots with Flash Exposure Compensation cranked way down and then way up -- you should easily be able to verify that flash intensity has changed.

If you get to the point where these things are working, you should be able to replicate remote control of additional flashes via one or more additional 622C units using the 60D's flash menu.